# Laser detector not compatible with Laser unit?

Tags: powertools

I have a self-leveling laser that produces a red beam in the range 635-650nm (Magnusson HL360) - it works great, I've not purchased a laser detector unit (DeWalt DE0892) that should detect red laser beam in outdoor conditions (30-50m) from the unit. According to the specification, it detects lasers in the range 630-680nm, however, when testing the detector it does sometimes detect laser and sometimes it does not (more often it does not). I thought that the unit will detect any red laser within its range but this does not seem to be the case?

Comment: Your problem may be the beam diverges as the distance increases lowering the beam density below the threshold trigger level. Solid state lasers that have collimating optics may not have the problem until further out. You can calculate the beam density at the source and size then the area at the target if the beam has gotten fairly large this may be the reason it is not detected remember the power density drops rapidly (Pi x R squared).

Comment: From my experience even laser detector not helps at sunny days. May work at dark or then clouds are heavy. That things increase the distance.

Comment: Green lasers are far better in the sun.  High quality red rotary lasers are fine in the sun but not to the same distance as in shade.  Rotary lasers have a huge advantage over non rotary lasers as the instantaneous beam power to get a given brightness is higher.

Comment: Sun light has no affect on the laser itself but a bright light can blind the detector no matter what the frequency (color). Green lasers spear to have more power because they are in the middle of our color spectrum where red is at the top. It all depends on the power of the individual system with class 3B being the highest available for these devices.